# How to list objects saved by SharedObject and how to remove all?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, shared-objects

How to list objects saved by SharedObject and how to remove all?

Example:

Three different SWF on the same site saved these objects:

```
SWF1:
    so = SharedObject.getLocal('game1');
    so.data....

SWF2:
    so = SharedObject.getLocal('gameBlue');
    so.data....

SWF3:
    so = SharedObject.getLocal('gameS4');
    so.data....
```

I'm writing SWF4 and I want to see all the objects stored on the site and I want to modify their data, or at least remove these shared objects

I found method `SharedObject.deleteAll('url')`, but when I try to use it, exception throws:

*"Error #2014: Feature is not available at this time."*

Comment: May be this will help somehow: http://www.techyv.com/questions/action-script-error-2014-adobe-air

Comment: Maybe this can help as well: http://www.flashguru.co.uk/delete-a-sharedobject

Comment: Can you be more precise in your end goal? What is the objective? Do you want to fallback to an initial state? What is it?